# Castle ActiveRecord: SessionScope.Current is null under IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, castle-activerecord, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm using ASP.Net MVC (still 1.0 for now) with Castle ActiveRecord and NHibernate.Linq. All is fine under IIS 6.

However, I'm faced with a problem deploying my app to IIS 7: ActiveRecord's SessionScope.Current seems to be not available for some reason.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the same web.config file on IIS7 and older versions, put the SessionScopeWebModule in the  section like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      <modules>
         <add name="ar.sessionscope" type="Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.SessionScopeWebModule, Castle.ActiveRecord" />
```

in addition to the original `<system.web>` section settings:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpModules>
              <add name="ar.sessionscope" type="Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.SessionScopeWebModule, Castle.ActiveRecord" />
```

Make sure you set the `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>` in the `<system.webServer>` section as well.

Comment: This totally saved me since I was drawing a blank as to why my session per request wasn't working (I had just copied the example from the Castle site).

Comment: Also to anyone else who comes along, as of Castle 3, the module is now in Castle.ActiveRecord.Web, so the entry above would actually look like this: <add name="ar.sessionscope" type="Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.SessionScopeWebModule, Castle.ActiveRecord.Web" />

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IIS 7 Integrated Mode you need to register the ActiveRecord HttpModule in the system.webServer/modules section instead of system.web/httpModules

See

- http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/168221.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx